# Getting warning messages : Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'min-chart' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, spfx-extensions, spfx-tooling

I am using third party css in SPFx. When I am building it, SPFx is showing me lots of warning messages :

[image]

I am using Windows 10 / SPFx 1.11.0.
Please let me know how to disable these warning messages.

Thanks,
Gaurav Goyal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resolution**

You should either fix all warnings or if it's not possible, you can ignore them.

For that purpose, you should modify your **gulpfile.js**.

There is one out of the box build suppression method call in **gulpfile**. You can add your own one using the same **build.addSuppression** method.

The method also accepts regexp, which is very convenient for us. Just add

```
build.addSuppression(/Warning - \[sass\] The local CSS class/gi);
```

or

```
build.addSuppression(/Warning/gi);
```

to ignore all warnings.

However, it's not very convenient, because probably you still want to see some warnings.
That's why a better idea would be ignoring some of them during the production bundle.

Modify your code a little bit:

```
let args = build.getConfig().args;
let isProductionBundle = args._.indexOf('bundle') !== -1 && (args.ship || args.production || args.p);

if (isProductionBundle) {
  build.addSuppression(/Warning - \[sass\] The local CSS class/gi);
  // OR
  build.addSuppression(/Warning/gi);
}
```

Source: https://spblog.net/post/2019/01/02/sharepoint-framework-development-some-gotchas-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working

Comment: regex ftw. I was able to filter only the third party classes from the results.