# Gulp bundle --ship: The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr error

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, gulp

I'm building a SharePoint SPFx and randomly when running `gulp bundle --ship` I get the following error:

```
The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr.
Exiting with exit code: 1
```

I saw this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968594/gulp-bundle-ship-the-build-failed-because-a-task-wrote-output-to-stderr
Which says to use `gulp bundle --debug` instead, which I did and that works, followed by `gulp package-solution --ship`. However, the output for the —debug switch and the —ship switch are sent to different folders. So when I try to deploy my build, it's the older version of the app.

I found other solutions that said adding `build.addSuppression()` to the `gulpfile.js`. I tried different things but none seem to fix the issue. Here is my `gulpfile.js`. The different `build.addSuppression()` are all the ones I tried.

```
'use strict';

const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

build.addSuppression(`Warning – [sass] src/webparts/components/customCSS.module.scss: filename should end with module.sass or module.scss`);
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

let args = build.getConfig().args;
let isProductionBundle = args._.indexOf('bundle') !== -1 && (args.ship || args.production || args.p);

if (isProductionBundle) {
  build.addSuppression(/Warning - \[sass\] The local CSS class/gi);
  // OR
  build.addSuppression(/Warning/gi);
}

build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

I tried all the solutions here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2131
Also Here: https://www.eliostruyf.com/how-to-let-the-warnings-not-fail-the-sharepoint-framework-build-process/
And Here: [Getting warning messages : Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'min-chart' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282956/getting-warning-messages-warning-sass-the-local-css-class-min-chart-is-n/282958#282958)

Comment: What version of node.js and SPFx do you use?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov Node version is `v10.16.0`. Where can I find SPFx version?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov if I'm looking at this correctly, SPFx is `1.10.0`